# Soundcloud, The configured redirect_uri of the client application is invalid

Tags: soundcloud

I'm getting the following error when trying to authenticate with soundcloud oauth.

```
"invalid_client: The configured redirect_uri of the client application is invalid."
```

I've checked other answers on stackoverflow, and the reasons listed there don't fit my scenario. I am using a valid url, and I can't seem to figure out where i'm going wrong here.

Redirect url: geula_archives.zalmanblau.com/soundcloud_redirect.php

Comment: Here's the full authentication url where i'm getting the error https://soundcloud.com/connect?client_id=p9Loe5L51v30LTjioj1qcBYZFJbRUrRX&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgeula_archives.zalmanblau.com%2Fsoundcloud_redirect.php&response_type=code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, there's an issue with handling subdomains that contain an underscore. Until that's fixed, you'll have to use a subdomain that does not contain an underscore.